# GoogleSpredsheets IMPORTRANGE форму не обновляет данные

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Ребята, кто может помочь , подскажите пожалуйста. У меня есть основная таблица товаров 1 Столбец - номер, 2 Столбец - название, 3 Столбец - код.

В таблицу сотруднику я создал формулу `importrange`. В основной моей таблице есть 3 товара. Они импортировались в таблицу сотруднику. Я добавил еще 3 товара, они в таблице сотрудника не появились. Так как ассортимент пополняется достаточно часто, нужно решить данную проблему. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать? Спасибо большое
http://joxi.ru/LmGgQ17teo97Zm

Ребят если у вас есть решение, пишите пожалуйста с формулой целиком.